# Trying to translate bash statement to subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess, output, pipeline, export-to-csv

I am trying to translate a bash command to a subprocess in python.  The bash command is:

cat LogFile.msg.log | grep ABCD | awk '{print $14,$10,$5,$7}' | sort -t' ' -k4 -n -r | head -10 > output.csv

So far I have the following for the subprocess:

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'LogFile.msg.log'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'ABCD'],
                        stdin=cat.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
awk = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '{print $14,$10,$5,$7}'],
                        stdin=grep.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-t','' '', '-k4', '-n', '-r'],
                        stdin=awk.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
head = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-10'],
                        stdin=sort.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
out = subprocess.Popen(['>', 'output.csv'],
                        stdin=head.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
end_of_pipe = out.stdout
```

Right now I'm receiving the following error:

```
Sort: empty tab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./latency2", line 39, in <module>
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but not sure what.

Comment: Are you sure your working directory is the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.  The first is that you're not translating the arguments to `sort` correctly.  When you run this `sort` command:

```
sort -t' ' -k4 -n -r
```

The shell pastes together the tokens `-t` and `' '` into the single argument `"-t "` (dash, tee, space).  So, the correct subprocess arguments for it should be:

```
sort = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-t ', '-k4', '-n', '-r'],
                        stdin=awk.stdout,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
```

The second problem is the final redirection to a file with the `> output.csv` tokens.  When the shell sees this, it doesn't run a command named `>`; rather, it opens the file `output.csv` for writing and sets that to the standard output handle of the last command.  So, you shouldn't be trying to run a command named `>` as a subprocess; you instead need to emulate the shell by opening a file:

```
head = subprocess.Popen(['head', '-10'],
                        stdin=sort.stdout,
                        stdout=open('output.csv', 'w'),  # Not a pipe here
                        )
```

Comment: That work perfectly.  I knew my output to .csv was jacked up.  Thanks!

Comment: I have one more question.  In my first line, I'm trying to search a file containing today's current date.  The bash statement works using LogFile_'date +%Y%m%d'.msg.log (LogFile_20120410.msg.log).  But this doesn't work in the subprocess.  I get "No Such File or directory."  Any ideas why this wouldn't translate correctly in the subprocess?

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite:

```
cat LogFile.msg.log | grep ABCD | awk '{print $14,$10,$5,$7}' |
sort -t' ' -k4 -n -r | head -10 > output.csv
```

in pure Python:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

select_items = itemgetter(13, 9, 4, 6) # note: zero-based indices
with open('LogFile.msg.log') as file, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    rows = (select_items(line.split()) for line in file if 'ABCD' in line)
    top10_rows = nlargest(10, rows, key=lambda row: int(row[3]))
    print("\n".join(map(" ".join, top10_rows)))
```